# What does CurrItems AWS metric show?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I am querying AWS `CurrItems` metric and it is showing me sum of all the items for last 24 hours as ~60Million.

I want to know if this 60M are just keys of different types (string, list, hash, set) or it includes hash field names and list elements as well.

Example:
If I have two keys of type string and hash then the metric will show 2 as output or it will include the count of fields from the hash also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.Redis.html), we can see `CurrItems`'s definition below

> The number of items in the cache. This is derived from the Redis keyspace statistic, summing all of the keys in the entire keyspace.

In Redis keyspace statistic, it only counts keys not their subkeys. I checked it works as I said.